# Conflicting types compilation error when my function has the same profile both in .h and .c files

Tags: c, gcc

I have the following compilation error:

```
gcc -Wall -ggdb -c code_generation.c
code_generation.c:3:6: error: conflicting types for ‘generateFile’
void generateFile(FILE *fp, char *filename, char *result){
     ^
code_generation.h:4:6: note: previous declaration of ‘generateFile’ was here
```

And I don't understand where it's coming from. Here is my function declaration in the code_generation.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void generateFile(FILE *fp, char *filename, char *result);
void generateInitDec(FILE *fp, char *filename);
```

And here is my definition in the code_generation.c file:

```
#include "code_generation.h"

void generateFile(FILE *fp, char *filename, char *result){
    char *res = NULL;

    memset(result, 0, sizeof(result));
    res = strrchr(filename, '.');
    if(res != NULL)
    *res = '\0';

    sprintf(result, "%s.nasm", filename);
    fp = fopen(result, "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%s 'io.asm'\n", "%include");
}
```

As you can see, both profiles are strictly the same, so I'm having a hard time understanding the error, and I don't understand how to correct it.

Could you fill me in on what is the meaning of this error, and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: As suggested, I addded -H to my compiler command line. I have the following lines when the compiler comes around code_generations.c/h:

```
gcc -Wall -ggdb -H -c code_generation.c
! code_generation.h.gch
 code_generation.c
```

When on other files, it looks like that:
    gcc -Wall -ggdb -H -c affiche_arbre_abstrait.c

With no further warning concerning the .h file.
My code_generation.h file isn't different than any other though, so where can it be coming from?

Comment: Can you post the full `.h` file? I feel like something critical is missing from it.

Comment: And also please show the *full* and *complete* error message. The compiler should have displayed some informational notes as well which would help us (and you) to figure out the problem.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` before your include so `FILE` is defined.

Comment: In the file you posted here, line 4 is empty.

Comment: This probably isn't what you want to hear but builds just fine for me (GCC 4.6.4). What compiler version are you using?

Comment: I edited my post to include what you wanted to see.

Comment: The code you posted here does not match your error message. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @N00byEdge GCC 5.4.0, and I never had such a problem. I already tried cleaning for potential obscure compilation errors, but that did nothing

Comment: I tried it on GCC 5.4 too, still building. Make sure you're including the correct file, that you've saved them, and that you're working in the correct directory.

Comment: Given the error message, and the other available information, I think you may find that the header you're using is not the one you think you're using.  Try adding `-H` to the compiler command line options.  It will print out the paths of the headers it is actually using.

Comment: Please read up about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  The code shown does not reproduce the problem — and the error messages you show do not match the code you show.  We can't guess what you're doing wrong if you don't provide us with the information we need.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler with -H option I have weird lines when the compilation arrives to code_generation.c/h. Adding them to my post.

Comment: Hmmm; I'm not sure about the `! code_generation.c.gch` line; is that a precompiled header of some sort — and does the `!` mean it is not actually used?  The other line isn't in a format I recognize; the output lines for headers start with a `.`, but you show the name of the `.c` source file.  I'd get rid of the `.gch` file and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in your compiler output:

```
! code_generation.h.gch
```

States that you are actually using a **precompiled header** (The `!` preceding it indicates that the file is valid).  This file can be generated if you compile a header file by itself as follows:

```
gcc -Wall -ggdb -c code_generation.h
```

If such a precompiled header exists, it will be used instead of the actual header file.    What happened is that you probably compiled this header file at a time when the signature of the function differed from what it is now, so now the contents of the .h file don't match what's in the .gch file.

Delete the .gch file and the compiler will use the .h file.